# How cl compiler deals with it when scanf encounters EOF (windows, VS2017)

Tags: c, cl

1. After I input CTRL+Z/ENTER 3 times, the scanf then return value of -1.
2. And scanf overlook all the things after 1st and 2nd EOF.
3. However while using gcc to compile, the scanf works well. (that is, return -1 as soon as enter an EOF.)

I have known from many books that scanf return EOF after encountering input  error or end-of-file. But cl works diffenrently. 
Why? Or something wrong with my comprehension about scanf?

Comment: The compiler doesn't really play into it, but the standard library implementation does. *And* the terminal used. When you use GCC and run the program, are you doing it from the Windows console (the old DOS prompt)?

Comment: @Some programmer dude Also in windows, mingw gcc for windows in fact.